# Rancher v2.0 proposed openebs deployment uses v0.6.0 helm template

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, openebs

while I was working on my rancher cluster I noticed these filesystem items in my backup .

```
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/.helmignore
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/Chart.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/README.md
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/app-readme.md
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/questions.yml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/NOTES.txt
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/_helpers.tpl
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/clusterrole.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/clusterrolebinding.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/cm-openebs-prometheus-config.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/cm-openebs-prometheus-tunables.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/crd-sp.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/crd-spc.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/deployment-maya-apiserver.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/deployment-maya-provisioner.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/deployment-maya-snapshot-operator.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/deployment-openebs-grafana.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/deployment-openebs-prometheus.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-cassandra.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-es-data-sc.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-jupyter.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-kafka.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-mongodb.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-percona.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-redis.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-standalone.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-standard.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-openebs-zk.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/sc-snapshot-promoter.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/service-maya-apiserver.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/service-openebs-grafana.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/service-openebs-prometheus.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-controller/cache/hash/proposed/openebs/v0.6/values.yaml
```

Looks like OpenEBS is not got updated in Rancher catalog. I can see latest OpenEBS version is 0.7.2 when I have seen on last of November 2018. How can i get the latest OpenEBS version in the Rancher catalog?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:
a) Upgrade your Rancher server to 2.1.x - OpenEBS v0.7.2 is available in the catalog shipping with the latest stable version of Rancher

b) If you don't want to upgrade then another alternative is to use the version from the helm catalog or a custom catalog